# Adding single product in multiple quantity to wishlist at a time from product details page

Tags: wishlist, quantity

On product details page, there is **QTY** textbox present, but that follows the "Add to Cart" button. 
Whatever quantity I add to it, will be accounted for "Adding the product to cart in that particular quantity"

But what i want is a similar textbox, that follows the "Add to Wishlist" button. How do I accomplish the task of adding the product to wishlist in the quanitity specified in a textbox?????

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default add to wishlist link does this already by working with the quantity options used for add to cart. It will submit the add to cart from but update the url to be that of the wish list and not the add to cart.

```
productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;
```

But if you are not working on a page that has an add to cart form then simply supply the input field with name `qty` and the default controller will take it from here.

You can also simply add the value via the url it wanted:

```
/wishlist/index/add/product/554/form_key/QOTCSV8HqoLA0K3T/qty/7
```

This will add 7 of the product 554 to the user's wishlist.